# Correct usage of unique_ptr in class member

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr

I am trying to really move from c++98 to c++11 and newer. I have wrapped my head over most of the new stuff but I am still not sure about the correct usage of `unique_ptr`.

Consider the example below, where class A has a unique_ptr member (I would have used raw pointer before!). This member variable should be assigned, when user needs, by calling a function somewhere else (not part of the class). Is this the correct usage? If not, what is the best alternative?

```
class A {
private:
   unique_ptr<MyType> mt;
public:
   void initStuff() {
      mt.reset(std::move(StaticFuncSomewhereElese::generateMyType()));
   } 
};

MyType* StaticFuncSomewhereElese::generateMyType() {
    MyType* temp = new MyType(...);
    //do stuff to temp (read file or something...)
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `std::move` there, raw pointers can't be moved.

Comment: @tuple_cat But this compiles and runs flawlessly

Comment: @SaeidYazdani You don't need it though. Rather use `std::make_unique()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then what would be the return type of the generator function?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani `std::unique_ptr<MyType>`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your code works fine (although the redundant* `move` can be omitted) but it would be better to construct the `unique_ptr` as early as possible:

```
class A {
private:
   std::unique_ptr<MyType> mt;
public:
   void initStuff() {
      mt = StaticFuncSomewhereElese::generateMyType();
   } 
};

std::unique_ptr<MyType> StaticFuncSomewhereElese::generateMyType() {
    auto temp = std::make_unique<MyType>(…);
    // `make_unique` is C++14 (although trivially implementable in C++11).
    // Here's an alternative without `make_unique`:
    // std::unique_ptr<MyType> temp(new MyType(…));

    //do stuff to temp (read file or something...)
    return temp;
}
```

This way it is clear that the return value of `generateMyType` must be deleted by the caller, and there's less possibility for memory leaks (e.g. if `generateMyType` returns early).

* The `move` is redundant because:

1. Raw pointers can't be moved.
2. The result of the `generateMyType()` expression is already an rvalue anyways.

Comment: Note that the question is tagged C++11, so it might be worth mentioning that `std::make_unique` wasn't introduced until C++14.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this the correct usage?

Besides `std::move` being redundant, yes this is correct. It is redundant because a) Bare pointers are copied, whether they are lvalues or rvalues and b) The function doesn't return a reference, so the return value is already an rvalue so there is no need to convert.

But there is room for improvement. In particular, I recommend to return a unique pointer from the factory function:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyType> StaticFuncSomewhereElese::generateMyType()
```

This prevents `temp` from leaking if the initialization throws an exception, and makes it much harder for the user of the factory to accidentally leak the returned pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it a generic template factory?

In header.

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> generateMyType();

classss A {
private:
   std::unique_ptr<MyType> mt;
   std::unique_ptr<MyOtherType> mot;
public:
   void initStuff() {
      mt = generateMyType<MyType>();
      mot = generateMyType<MyOtherType>();
   } 
};
```

And in the source file

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> generateMyType()
{
  auto temp = std::make_unique<T>();
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would like to add that you may need to define copy constructor and assignment operator for your class.

I used a vector of such class, `std::vector<MyClass>`, and run into a problem. It feels obvious when you think about it as `vector` needs a way to copy the data over if it needs to relocate. You can not trivially copy the member that is a `unique_ptr`, thus the need to write the copy constructor for the class containing smart pointer.

I wrote a non-const copy constructor to move the pointer to resolve my issue.

Comment: Actually, all you need is a move constructor for `MyClass`. Writing a copy constructor for a class containing a `unique_ptr` is somewhat complicated -- for starters, you have to define what it actually should do. Writing a move constructor, on the other hand, is trivial.

Comment: I will look at writing the move contstructor instead. Thanks for the information. I felt the discussion for the class containing unique_ptr was needed as I did not see this caveat being pointed out.